# VSCode não abre página no navegador

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Seguinte, instalei o PHP Debug no VS Code assim como ensina esse site https://imasters.com.br/back-end/configurando-debugger-php-no-vs-code, porém, ao executar, o vs não abre a página no browser. Alguém sabe o porque?

**laucher.json** (Testei usar a porta 80 que é a q eu uso no wamp, mesmo assim não vai).

```
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
```

**php.ini** (isso foi adicionado ao adicionar a extensão Debug)

```
   xdebug.remote_enable = off
   xdebug.profiler_enable = off
   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
   xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
   xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
   xdebug.show_local_vars=0
   zend_extension = \php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll // esse arquivo está na mesma pasta do php.ini
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Comment: O artigo é para usar o XDebug para depurar o script direto no console do VSCode, se entendi, abrir o navegador é algo complicado, o Apache usa rotas virtuais e não fisicas, claro que deve ser possivel apontar um arquivo para abrir **"com HTTP"**, mas se dependerá muito de configurar o Apache (Wamp, xampp, easyphp todos usam apache, que é o servidor http, o PHP é apenas o interpretador de scripts, apesar de ter um mini servidor embutido). Exemplo ao usar um framework de rotas mesmo que o VSCode abrisse o navegador não iria entender bem as rotas, como Laravel, pois os caminhos não são fisicos.

Comment: Se for só abrir no browser vc pode usar alguma extensão tipo a Live Server que pode resolver.

Comment: Guilherme, normalmente uso o wamp com o netbeans, e abre, você acha que pode ser alguma coisa com o VSCode? (Estou querendo usar o VS por ele ser mais leve que o netbeans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma extensão "PHP Server" que inicia um servidor PHP built-in, acho que por padrão na porta 3000. Após a instalação da extensão, `Ctrl+Shift+P`, atalho para a Command Palette, busque PHP Server, um 'ps' já traz como resultado dependendo das suas extensões, e Enter. Abrirá, então, o arquivo no browser. Poderá também usar o botão direito do mouse e a opção PHP Server: Open file in Browser.

Segue um ótimo artigo mostrando passo a passo como habilitar essa extensão e outras com finalidade de debbug de código PHP:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/debugando-c%C3%B3digo-php-com-xdebug-visual-studio-code-ricardo-torquato/

Answer (score 0):

Olá

É simples aperta **`Ctrl+Shift+D`** tecla de atalho, vai aparecer Lounch Chrome against localhost canto superior esquerdo, do lado vai ter a configuração do launch.json abre ele

vai está com essas configurações:

```
{
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

na url: você altera para onde está o arquivo no diretório Ex:

```
            "url":"http://localhost/nomeDirA/nomeDirB/nomedoArquivo.php,
```

Pronto só da Start Debugging que vai abrir o arquivo no Browser.

Answer (score -1):

Se estiverem utilizando a partir da versão 5.4 do PHP, é possivel rodar o comando

```
 php -S localhost:8000
```

direto no terminal/prompt dentro do seu diretório do projeto. Depois é só acessar o navegador através de http://localhost:8000

Espero que tenha ajudado.
Abraços

Answer (score -3):

Olá,

Faça manualmente o processo com o VSCODE. Abra o navegador e digite:

```
localhost/nomedapastadoseuprojeto
```

Outro ponto é verificar sua utilização de frameworks que podem ter portas específicas definidas, por exemplo o Angular que usa a `4200` (pelo menos aqui no meu pc).